# chrome no reconoce justify-self: center

Tags: css3, grid

Buen dia, Estoy usando la grid de css por primera vez y en mozilla todo perfecto, pero en chrome no me toma el justify-self. Ahi alguna compatibilidad que no conozca??

Paso el codigo para que vean que puede ser. Gracias

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "futura Lt BT";
  font-size: 16px;
}

.contenedor {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}


/*principal producto*/

main {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;
}

main #institucional {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}


/*imagenes principales*/

main #institucional #imagenes {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  height: 200px;
}

main #institucional #imagenes #uno {
  background: yellow;
}

main #institucional #imagenes #dos {
  background: red;
}

main #institucional #imagenes #tres {
  background: blue;
}

main #institucional #imagenes #cuatro {
  background: blueviolet;
}


/*logo principal circular*/

main #institucional #logoPrincipal {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: orange;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: -1;
  position: absolute;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}


/*promo vigente del mes*/

main .promo {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>PROMO Exclusive 2020</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalizr.css" />
  <script src="js/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <main>
      <div id="institucional">
        <div id="imagenes">
          <img id="uno" src="#" alt="1" />
          <img id="dos" src="#" alt="2" />
          <img id="tres" src="#" alt="3" />
          <img id="cuatro" src="#" alt="4" />
        </div>
        <div id="logoPrincipal">
          <img src="#" alt="logo exclusive" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola. Acabo de probar tu código en mozilla y chromium y efectivamente se muestra diferente en ambos. Consulte en MDN y encontre: **"La propiedad CSS align-self alinea los elementos flexibles de la línea flexible actual, reemplazando el valor de align-items. Si el límite transversal de alguno de los elementos está definido como auto, el valor de align-self es ignorado."** Quizás tenga que ver. [align-self](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/align-self)

Comment: elimine todos los "auto" que tenia configurados en el codigo (tuvieran o no que ver con la seccion para descartar conflictos) pero no es eso lo que esta anulando el comando align-items.... Lo unico que veo en consola es que "user agent stylesheet" le da un display:block que no logro anular...no se si sera eso lo que entra en conflicito

Comment: tambien probe agregar -webkit-box-align: center; y no funciono...

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Chrome utilizas?

Comment: Versión 80.0.3987.87 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cuando un elemento tiene una posición absoluta, este deja de tener el comportamiento de su contenedor y pasa a tener un comportamiento escalado a los contenedores superiores hasta el global, es decir, en tu caso el elemento hijo es un `grid-item` pero al tener la posición absoluta este deja de ser parte del `grid` (algo que cambiaron en versiones algo antiguas de WebKit y Chromium).

La solución a esto es siempre que se use un position absolute en un elemento poner la posición relativa a su contenedor para mantener el control, no sólo por Chrome, sino también por otros como Safari o Edge. En tu caso agregando un `position: relative` a `main #institucional` lo arregla.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "futura Lt BT";
  font-size: 16px;
}

.contenedor {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}


/*principal producto*/

main {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;
}

main #institucional {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}


/*imagenes principales*/

main #institucional #imagenes {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  height: 200px;
}

main #institucional #imagenes #uno {
  background: yellow;
}

main #institucional #imagenes #dos {
  background: red;
}

main #institucional #imagenes #tres {
  background: blue;
}

main #institucional #imagenes #cuatro {
  background: blueviolet;
}


/*logo principal circular*/

main #institucional #logoPrincipal {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: orange;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: -1;
  position: absolute;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}


/*promo vigente del mes*/

main .promo {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>PROMO Exclusive 2020</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalizr.css" />
  <script src="js/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <main>
      <div id="institucional">
        <div id="imagenes">
          <img id="uno" src="#" alt="1" />
          <img id="dos" src="#" alt="2" />
          <img id="tres" src="#" alt="3" />
          <img id="cuatro" src="#" alt="4" />
        </div>
        <div id="logoPrincipal">
          <img src="#" alt="logo exclusive" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Creo que el motivo que das no es correcto (aunque tu código haga que se vea bien), `absolute` indica posición absoluta respecto al contenedor (el padre). Lo que tu dices ocurre cuando usas `fixed`.

Comment: @PabloLozano mira este ejemplo que hice rápido https://jsfiddle.net/cxdamk4w/ de hecho puedes probar en cualquier navegador (incluso Firefox), se puede ver la diferencia de usar/no_usar `position: relative` con `position: absolute` (en ningún caso usé `fixed` el cual por cierto en ningún caso toma la posición del padre).

Comment: @PabloLozano ah ok, ya entendí tu observación, ahí edité esa parte de mi respuesta para que sea más claro :)

Comment: perfecto! muchisimas gracias por el aporte